# SignalR : How can I broadcast message to Other page of the application

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I am creating a test app, where one can download some files and on download success notification will be propagated to admin ,something like notification in 
www.ge.tt,or panel notification in Facebook.

I have two pages

a)`Download.aspx`

b)`LandingPage.aspx`

In `Download.aspx`

```
    function PushNotification() {
        alert("I ran Upto Here");
        //Declare a proxy to Reference a Hub
        var notification = $.connection.notificationHub;

        //Start a Connection
        $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
            notification.server.send(21);
            //$("#hdnFileId").val()
            alert("I ran Upto Here 2 ");


        });
        notification.client.broadcastMessage = function (FileID) {

            alert("file was Downloaded" + FileID);
        };
    }
```

Here two different tabs/browser are working Fine showing `alert` message if page Loads.

but i want to use the brodcast message in my `LandingPage.aspx`

here is the Js

```
$(function () {

var notification = $.connection.notificationHub;

    notification.client.broadcastMessage = function (FileID) {

    alert("file was Downloaded" + FileID);
};

});
```

And my hubclass ..

```
namespace TestApplication.Entities
{
  public class NotificationHub : Hub
  {
    //public void Hello()
    //{
    //    Clients.All.hello();
    //}

    public void Send(int FileID)
    {
        Clients.All.broadcastMessage(FileID);
    }
}
}
```

but the notification is not coming here, whats wrong Here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't start connection in `LandingPage.aspx`

Try like this in `LandingPage.aspx`

```
var notification = $.connection.notificationHub;
$.connection.hub.start(); 
notification.client.broadcastMessage = function (FileID) {
   alert("file was Downloaded" + FileID);
};
```